# Secure Spring REST Service using spring-security-oauth2 2.0.5.RELEASE

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have been searching for an example Spring Webservice which is being protected using oauth 2.0..

Looking around I found https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2 but there some files seems to be missing from the project.

Two things that I am looking for is :

- When user authenticates, user name and password goes to /login.do , now I can not understand how this Servlet is being configured, if its not controller. web.xml is missing.
- When I try to see how beans configured then applicationContext.xml is also missing. I am not able to find those files in order to see how things are configured.

**Help Required :**

- Should I use annotation in order to configure my web service or xml configuration. I am willing to use the latest version, and leverage advanced configurations, for better security.
- I have another Single page application ( HTML5 ) , which accesses data from this spring web service, which is being hosted on Google App Engine. My ultimate objective is to create a chrome plugin of (html5) pages and use my service from there..

Please suggest a better path so that I can achieve my objectives.

Best regards,
Shashank Pratap

Comment: Hi, Firstly, I wish someone could just let me know to better protect my web service using oauth 2.0. I am looking for some technical stuff.

Comment: Servlet 3.0 doesn't require a web.xml anymore (you might want to update your knowledge on the servlet specs). Spring advocates java based configuration instead of xml. So nothing is missing ...

Comment: Too broad, please ask one question at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Apologize for late reply.

1) Regarding Oauth2.0 implementation : Since GAE does not support Servlet 3.0 therefore, developer is restricted to servlet 2.5. Therefore I found that we are restricted to 1.0.5.RELEASE. I was able to configure it successfully.

**Best Practice on GAE** : Rather than following this approach, I would suggest others to use Google Endpoints. As it supports oauth2.0 as well as we can develop REST API relatively quickly.

**Scale ability and Response time** : Since I was using Spring dependency injection along with spring security, application responded slower than the combination of Google Endpoints and Google Juice, as juice does injection just in time, where as spring prepares everything as soon as new instance starts, which created problem for me.

2) Chrome Plugin is completely different story. :-)

Please correct if I am wrong.
Thanks,
Shashank Pratap